# Courage vs. Courageousness

Tags: derivation

Courage is "the ability to do something that frightens one" *(New Oxford American Dictionary)*. Courageousness is also a word in the dictionary.

Do they mean the same thing, and if so, how did "courageousness" become a word?

There are other examples of this: "trust" and "trustworthiness". What is going on with the other examples?

Comment: One is a noun, the other is an adjective.

Comment: @Laurel   Which ones are adjectives?

Comment: The ones ending in -ness. (You can get this information from a dictionary, you know...)

Comment: @Laurel actually, M-w.com says "-ness" is a noun suffix.  (It is applied to adjectives, and turns them into nouns.)

Comment: As a noun, trust is either the state of trusting or the magnitude of trusting.  Trustworthiness is how much someone deserves to be trusted.   I can have trust for an untrustworthy person or little trust for a trustworthy person.  I don't see any similar distinction for courage and courageousness, though I guess you could convince me that courage applies to actions during frightening circumstances and courageousness applies to a person's character and tendencies to display courage.

Comment: @jejorda2 I would say courageousness is only used as an opposite word to weakness. Also, it is very rarely used.

Comment: @Laurel You can't, thankfully, get that sort of stuff from a dictionary. Time to delete.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What dictionary are you using that doesn't say what part of speech things are? Because that's what I meant..

Comment: @Laurel New Oxford American Dictionary... the one build into OS X Yosemite

Comment: @Laurel _Centaurus_: 'Which ones are adjectives?' _[You]_: 'The ones ending in -ness.  (You can get this information from a dictionary, you know...)'  No; dictionaries state that 'courageousness', 'trustworthiness', 'courage' and 'trust' are **all** nouns. Read Josh's answer.

Comment: [A Google search for “Courage vs Courageousness”](https://www.google.com/#q=Courage+vs+Courageousness) led me to [the-difference-between.com](http://the-difference-between.com/courage/courageousness) (really; there’s a site by that name!), which says, “the difference between **courage** and **courageousness** is that **courage** is the quality of a confident character not to be afraid or intimidated easily but without being incautious or inconsiderate while **courageousness** is the state of being courageous.”  Sounds to me like the sound of one hand waving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different origins, *courage* is  from Old French, while *courageousness* is  from the  usage to make nouns from adjectives adding the suffix *-ness* from Old English, a common practice with abstract nouns:

***[-ness:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ness?s=t)*** meaning and usage

> - a native English suffix attached to adjectives and participles, forming abstract nouns denoting quality and state (and often, by extension, something exemplifying a quality or state):
>   *darkness; goodness; kindness; obligingness; preparedness*.

(Dictionary.com)

***[-ness](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ness)*** (origin):

> - word-forming element denoting action, quality, or state, attached to an adjective or past participle to form an abstract noun, from Old English -nes(s), ..................abstract noun suffix, probably from the same root as Latin -tudo (see -tude).

***[courage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=courage)***(origin):

> - 1300, from Old French corage (12c., Modern French courage) "heart***, innermost feelings; temper," from Vulgar Latin *coraticum (source of Italian coraggio, Spanish coraje), from Latin cor "heart,

(Etymonline)